# "no-unused-expressions" error in react with map function

Tags: reactjs, components, es6-map

I made an 'App' class and passed a state as props in a child 'Todos' component.

Have a look at my code:

```
class App extends Component {

  state = {
  todos:[
    {
      id:1,
      title:'task1',
      complete:false,
    },{
      id:2,
      title:'task2',
      complete:false,
    },{
      id:3,
      title:'task3',
      complete:false,
    }
  ]
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Todos todos={this.state.todos}/>
    </div>
  );
 }
}
```

My Todos Component:

```
class Todos extends Component {
  render() {
    return this.props.todos.map((list)=>{list.title});
  }
}
```

Now inside my Todos component in map function,it's not allowing me to use curly braces but if I replace it by round bracket,it's fine,Why?

Please help me.Sorry for badly structured question.

Comment: It doesn't return anything with the curly braces unless you use an explicit `return`. What's the warning? Is it telling you that the mapping function returns `undefined`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use curly braces, that means you are writing a function, and you should return some `jsx` in the end, But  your code is are not returning any `jsx`. 
So the valid code would be

```
return this.props.todos.map((list)=>{ return list.title});
```

and the code with round brackets work because it is a short hand to write a return.
So basically with round brackets, your code is still like this

```
return this.props.todos.map((list)=>{ return list.title});
```

Some valid ways:

```
return this.props.todos.map((list)=>{ return list.title});

return this.props.todos.map((list)=> list.title);
```